# How to flip by Y venn diagramm? (venn.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, venn-diagram, venn.js

I have simple venn diagramm built with d3.js and venn.js: https://jsfiddle.net/rvuf1z5o/

```
var sets = [
    {sets: ['F'], size: 3},
    {sets: ['G'], size: 3},
    {sets: ['C'], size: 3},
    {sets: ['F','G'], size: 1},
    {sets: ['F','C'], size: 1},
    {sets: ['G','C'], size: 1},
    {sets: ['F','G','C']}
];

var chart = venn.VennDiagram();
var div = d3.select("#venn").datum(sets).call(chart);
```

I need to flip this chart by Y as shown in the picture:
[image]

How can I do it using sets / chart object / svg attrs / css?

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though you can rearrange their positions by switching around what order you declare the sets. Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvuf1z5o/1/)

```
var sets = [
{sets: ['F'], size: 3},
{sets: ['G'], size: 3},
{sets: ['C'], size: 3},

{sets: ['G','C'], size: 1},
{sets: ['F','C'], size: 1},
{sets: ['F','G'], size: 1},

{sets: ['F','G','C']}
];

var chart = venn.VennDiagram();
var div = d3.select("#venn").datum(sets).call(chart);
```

The modified code is at the bottom as I had to paste in venn.js

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer.